# Rate my Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

Here's the `Makefile` I've built up over the last two years which I use as a template (most often verbatim apart from target name(s)). It's meant to be used for C exclusively.

I've sort of cobbled it together, so it's very well possible I made a bone-headed mistake somewhere, hence why I'd like some more experienced eyes to review it! If there's anything that needs explaining, please comment and I'll update the post.

```
TARGETS := target

CC := gcc

CFLAGS       := -c -W -Wall -pedantic -O3
DEBUG_CFLAGS := -c -W -Wall -pedantic -g -Og

LDFLAGS       := -lm 
DEBUG_LDFLAGS := -g $(LDFLAGS)

BINDIR    := ./bin
DEBUGDIR  := ./debug
OBJDIR    := ./obj
SRCDIR    := ./src
TESTDIR   := ./test

SOURCES      := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
MAINS        := $(TARGETS:%=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
OBJECTS      := $(filter-out $(MAINS), $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o))
DEBUGOBJECTS := $(OBJECTS:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=$(DEBUGDIR)/%.do)
DEBUGTARGETS := $(TARGETS:%=%.db)

TESTSOURCES := $(wildcard $(TESTDIR)/*.c)
TESTS       := $(TESTSOURCES:$(TESTDIR)/%.c=$(BINDIR)/%)

all  : $(TARGETS)
debug: $(DEBUGTARGETS)
test : $(TESTS)

$(TARGETS): % : $(OBJDIR)/%.o $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(MAINS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(DEBUGTARGETS): $(DEBUGOBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(DEBUG_LDFLAGS)

$(DEBUGOBJECTS): $(DEBUGDIR)/%.do : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(DEBUGDIR)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(TESTS): $(BINDIR)/%_test : $(TESTDIR)/%_test.c $(filter-out $(MAINS), $(OBJECTS))
    mkdir -p $(TESTDIR)
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
    $@

clean: 
    rm -f $(MAINS) $(OBJECTS) $(TARGETS) $(TESTS)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Not Enough `CFLAGS`

You currently have `c -W -Wall -pedantic -O3`.  First, `-c` shouldn’t be there; it just stops you from using `CFLAGS` in a single-stage compile.  Move it to the targets that create object files.

You don’t specify a version of the language on the command line, despite asking for `-pedantic` warnings.  GCC defaults to `-std=c90`, while I would normally use `-std=c17`, but whatever your project uses, make it explicit and make sure everyone knows what they’re supposed to be using.

There are a lot more useful warnings that you haven’t enabled, for example, implicit conversion between signed and unsigned.  I typically use `-std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wdeprecated`.

If you set out to remove all warnings (disabling any specific ones that you decide not to fix, and fixing the rest), you might want `-Werror`.

You don’t specify a submodel, but it’s very unlikely that you would want to release software that needs to run on the very earliest x86-64 CPUs without AVX or even `cmpxchg16b`.  Or if you’re compiling and testing binaries that only you will use, and what you share will be the source, you should always add `-march=native`.

You likely also want `-flto` for whole-program optimization, in your release build.

I typically set the POSIX feature-test macros in a header that I include at the top of all source files, but you could set that here if you prefer.

### Consider a Few Debug Flags

You currently have `-Og`, which is a good choice for debug optimization.  There is no reason not to also add `-march=native`.  If you wrote any tail-recursive calls, you might also need `-foptimize-sibling-calls` to avoid a stack overflow.

### Do You Really Want to Compile and Link Every file in the Directory?

For example, if you create `fop.o` instead of `foo.o` by a typo, should that always be linked in?  Better to keep a list of what object files you’re supposed to have.

### What if a Header Changes?

Listing the object files also lets you specify header files as dependencies, so that the correct files get recompiled when you edit a header.

### Your `make clean` Does not Clean Up Your Debug Builds

Your `debug` target creates `*.do` and `*.db` files, which your `clean` target never cleans.

Comment: About the C version, that is a recent omission. I used to compile with `std=c89` but my recent systems programming class uses system calls that are not available, and I opted for the unsafe but easy answer of just removing the argument.

Comment: @ice-wind System calls that aren’t available are typically enabled by the `_XOPEN_SOURCE` (and optionally `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`) macros. Unless they’re GNU extensions, or ANSI later than C89. The `man` page should tell you what standard they conform to.

Comment: If they’re POSIX, see `man feature_test_macros` for the correct value to set.

Answer (score 1):

Some desirable additions:

- Annotate the targets that don't generate a file matching the target name:

  ```
  .PHONY: all clean debug test
  ```
- Ensure that any failing command doesn't leave a partially-written output file:

  ```
  .DELETE_ON_ERROR:
  ```

  Most modern C compilers are reasonably good at avoiding this problem, but it's effectively free to get Make to support you here.  It's a good habit to have in Makefiles.
- Use built-in variable `$(RM)` instead of writing `rm -f` in full.  This might ease the path towards portability beyond just POSIX, too.
- `mkdir -p` can fail if another target is concurrently creating the same directory.  Either make the directory an order-only dependency, or use a command like `@test -d $(@D) || mkdir $(@D) 2>/dev/null || test -d $(@D)` (I generally create a variable for that, rather than writing it out in every rule that needs a target directory creating).

A reasonably diligent build setup won't even attempt to compile the release version unless the tests pass.  I suggest making each `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` depend on the corresponding debug object's tests to facilitate that.

Comment: Thank you, those all seem to be good pieces of advice ! I am going to implement some if not all of them.